# Remove n characters from string c++

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble removing characters from a string. In my function, I have an int (`n`) and a string (`str`). I need to enter an int, then remove the first `n` characters of that string.

For example:

```
int n = 2
string str = hello

output: llo
```

I'm not allowed to use any string functions other than `size()`, otherwise I already know about `erase()` so I would have just used that.

I asked a friend for help, but he couldn't figure it out, either.

Here's what I have so far:

```cpp
string removeFirst(string str, int n){
    //input: a string (str) and an integer (n)
    //output: a string with all but the first n characters of str

    string rv = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
        if(str.size() >= n){
            rv = i;
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

I'm fairly certain I need to use something along the lines of `str[n]`, but I'm not too sure.

I know it's simple, but I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: `rv = i`??? How exactly are you hoping for a `string` to get the value of an `int`???

Comment: `rv = i;` is assigning an integer index to the string `rv`. You probably want to concatenate, not assign, and you want to concatenate the character *at* that index, not the index itself. `if(str.size() >= n)` also doesn't seem like quite the right comparison. `str.size()` is fixed if you don't modify `str`, which you don't. What are you *actually* checking for in that conditional?

Comment: Also, doing `x = y` repeatedly inside a `for` loop means that by the time the loop completes, `x` will get only the last value assigned to it, so your code seems useless even regardless of what I've mention above.

Comment: @goodvibration That's just what my friend told me to try so that's just what's in my code as of right now. I've tried a bunch of other things so if you'd like my to edit with something different I can!

Comment: @Nathan Pierson I kinda just figured I needed an if statement in the case that n was larger than str.size().

Comment: @goodvibration so how else should I loop through the string then? would a while loop be better?

Comment: So right now it seems like the problem is that you haven't really thought through what your code is supposed to be doing. Try writing out what you want the code to do, step by step. Then start asking how to translate those simple steps into C++ code.

Comment: You said "then remove all but the first n characters of that string" but the first n characters are removed in the example. Which is really expected?

Comment: [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is useful to concatenate things without using (function of) `std::string` directly.

Comment: @NathanPierson Understood. Okay so I need to initialize rv to pass the outputted string into, then loop through str.size(), if str.size() >= n (in the case n is less than str.size(), it'll output the original string), then remove the first n characters of str, and pass that output to rv. I just don't know how to remove said characters only using .size().

Comment: @MikeCAT My bad, I mistyped. I fixed it!

Comment: @ethanh You're still describing it pretty much at the level of code, and code you don't seem to understand at that. I'm thinking of a description like "Look at every letter in the input string. If it's supposed to go in the output string, add it to the output string. If not, skip it." And then start asking yourself "How do I look at every letter? How do I decide whether it's supposed to go in the output string or not? How do I add a character to a string once I've decided I should?" But I see people have just posted working code samples below, so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to modify input string

```
string removeFirst(string str, int n){
    //input: a string (str) and an integer (n)
    //output: a string with all but the first n characters of str

    string rv = "";
    if (n >= str.size())
    {   
        return rv;
    }    
    for(int i = n; i < str.size(); ++i){
        rv+=str[i];
    }
    return rv;
}
```

if you want to modify your input string

```
void removeFirst(string &str, int n){
    //input: a string (str) and an integer (n)
    //output: a string with all but the first n characters of str

    if (n >= str.size())
    {   
        str="";
        return ;
    }    
    for(int i=0;i<str.size()-n;i++)
    {
        str[i]=str[i+n];
    }
    for(int i=str.size()-n;i<str.size();i++)
    {
        str[i]='\0';
    }
  return;
}
```

Comment: `str[i]` uses [`operator[]`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string/op_at.html), which is a string function other than `size()`.

Comment: str[i] is allowed. I think what my professor meant by only using str.size() is we can only get the output using that function and not something like the erase function. The first example works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the loop, like this:

```
string removeFirst(string str, int n) {
    
    string rv = "";

    for (int i = n; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        rv += str[i];
    }
    
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: `str[i]` uses [`operator[]`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string/op_at.html), which is a string function other than `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is useful to do operation with strings without directly touching that.

Example:

```
#include <sstream>

string removeFirst(string str, int n){
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::stringstream ret;
    // drop first n characters
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) ss.get();
    // read rest of string
    int c;
    while ((c = ss.get()) != EOF) {
        ret << static_cast<char>(c);
    }
    // return the result
    return ret.str();
}
```